# EventTrigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to get the SelectedItems from the Listbox where the Checkbox is selected via the InvokeCommandAction and store them in an obsevableCollection SelectedItems , but I am not getting the SelectedItemChangedCommand working(break point does not hit) and not sure how do I populate the Items in the SelectedItems Collection.   I tried following, hoping that once the checkbox is checked or unchecked, the SelectedItemChangedCommand would be called and I can have a method getting called on this where I will populate the SelectedItems

Please note I am looking for a way to achieve this without any code behind.

```
 <ListBox Margin="45,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
         SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="146">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <CheckBox Margin="5,2"
                                  IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </CheckBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Updated Xaml File

```
<Window x:Class="stack.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stack"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Margin="45,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 

                 ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="146">
            <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <CheckBox 
                                Margin="5,2" 
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            >
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </CheckBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"  
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am binding the listbox to observableCollection ListItems defined in view model as

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace stack
{


    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ListItems { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedListItems { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand SelectedItemChangedCommand { get; set; }

        public string _selectedItem;
        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }

        public bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ListItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ListItems.Add("One");
            ListItems.Add("Two");
            ListItems.Add("three");
            ListItems.Add("Four");
            ListItems.Add("Five");
            SelectedItemChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteItemChanged);
        }

        public void ExecuteItemChanged(object parameter)
        {
            if (IsSelected)
            {
                SelectedListItems.Add(SelectedItem);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChangedEventHandler = PropertyChanged;
            _propertyChangedEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` is cheap, but it doesn't do two-way bindings. Thus, the items aren't getting selected. You need a regular binding with a `RelativeSource` of `TemplatedParent`:

```
<CheckBox 
    Margin="5,2" 
    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
    >
```

Note that you are binding `CheckBox.IsChecked` to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`. The templated parent is a ListBoxItem, not your main viewmodel.

Second, you want to pass the `SelectedItems`, plural, property to your command. `SelectedItem` is *singular*. It's only one item. It'll be the topmost selected item when many are selected. You have SelectionMode="Multiple" on your listbox, so I assume you want the full selection.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
    Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItems}"
    />
```

And make sure you have `x:Name="myListBox"` on the ListBox: The CommandParameter binding needs that to find SelectedItems.

Finally: ExecuteItemChanged() is very broken. Your main viewmodel properties `IsSelected` and `SelectedItem` are not bound to anything. They're just false and null, always. Every time the selection changes, you execute the command and pass in the *first* selected item as `parameter`, and then you ignore it and go look to see if `false` is still `false`, which it is. If it weren't, your *viewmodel's* SelectedItem property would still be null, because you never updated that either.

Here's what you want to do: When the selection changes, pass the entire collection of currently selected items into your command. Replace the viewmodel's entire collection of currently selected items with the current state from the control. You must, must, must bind SelectedItems as the CommandParameter above.

Get rid of `SelectedItem` and `IsSelected` on the viewmodel, they serve no purpose.

If possible, don't ever get into this business of maintaining two lists and trying to keep them in sync piecemeal. It's always a mess. And you don't need to do it in this case.

```
public void ExecuteItemChanged(object parameter)
{
    //  ListBox.SelectedItems is System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection,
    //  a precambrian monster that's declared internal in PresentationFramework.dll. 
    //  However, it does implement non-generic IList, so cast it to that. 
    if (parameter is System.Collections.IList selectedItems)
    {
        if (SelectedListItems == null)
        {
            SelectedListItems = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        }

        SelectedListItems.Clear();

        foreach (string item in selectedItems)
        {
            SelectedListItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the Xaml file as per your suggestion, still I could not get the Selected Items populated :-( , I have pasted my completed ViewModel Class now here. I guess I am missing something else

Comment: `ExecuteItemChanged(object parameter)` is broken. What's the `SelectedItem` property of the viewmodel? Null. It's not bound. You go to all this trouble to pass in the first selected item from the listbox as `parameter` to the command, and then you ignore it. What's `IsSelected` on the viewmodel? It's false. You never bind it, you never set it. Why would it magically have the same value as some random property of one out of a whole collection of checkboxes off in the UI somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to have Multiple selections from the Listbox, as you can see there are checkboxes inside listboxes, I have seen some posts, they use eventhandlers in code behind, But I want to achieve this without using any code behind.I am new to the MVVM so trying this out first time

Comment: @RajeevVerma Use codebehind when you need to. MVVM does not mean "no codebehind"; it means "use codebehind for logic that belongs to the view, and the viewmodel for logic that belongs to the viewmodel". Usually there isn't *much* logic that belongs to the view, but there's often some, and codebehind is fine for its intended purpose.

Comment: understood, I was trying out multiple things, and was pasting code in chunks here, which resulted in pasting this version of ExecuteItemChanged() along with those unused properties 
Thanks for your response and your explanation on the code behind +1 for your comment on this.